# How to modify a global struct when passed as a parameter to a function (c++)?

Tags: c++, struct, parameters, scope

let's say I have this global struct

```
struct input_shift_register
{
    bool not_used;
    int data;
    int *ptr_to_data;
};
```

and I would want to pass an instance of it in a function to modify its data

```
void share_data(input_shift_register shift) {
shift.data = 5;
}
```

This will only modify the local copy of the struct inside the function. How can I modify the "real" global struct instead? I am sorry this is probably very easy but I just can't find an answer online.

Comment: Use pass-by-reference (declare parameter as `input_shift_register &shift`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have 2 options.

- Pass by reference

```
void share_data(input_shift_register& shift) {
  shift.data = 5;
}
```

This will make sure your function parameter is a reference(alias) bound to the function argument, hence you are dealing with the actual variable which is passed to the function at the calling site.

- Pass by pointer

```
void share_data(input_shift_register* shift) {
  shift->data = 5;
}
```

This will make sure you are passing the address of the variable, hence at the calling site you should pass the address as the argument i.e. `share_data(&shift_register);`.

If you do pass by value(as in your code), it will simply pass a copy of the argument and the function will work with that copy, not with the actual variable.

For a detailed discussion have a look at the following.

[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

Pass-by reference and Pass-by value are the two ways you can use for your specific needs.

However, you can also try this:

```
input_shift_register share_data(input_shift_register shift) 
{
    shift.data = 5;
    return shift;
}


input_shift_register var;
var = share_data(var)
```

If you define you function in this way, then the caller has a choice to either assign the returned value of the function to either the original `var` or to some other variable of the same struct.

This is the another way of doing the same thing. I wouldn't say it is best-optimized but it may suit some of the specific requirements.